# How to plot daily averages with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

This should be very easy, but I'm having several issues. The thing is, I want to do something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466306/using-pandas-to-find-daily-averages), but (1) I have a datetime field, so I have the hour, minutes and seconds in my date column, (2) I want to plot a line graph by day.

So, this is my data:

```
date                   col1        col2
2020-01-01 00:01:020   20          500
2020-01-02 00:01:020   10          500
2020-01-02 00:01:000   20          500
2020-01-02 00:01:021   20          500
2020-02-05 20:11:010   30          500
2020-02-05 10:01:020   10          500
.
.
.
```

So, as I mentioned above, what I want is to plot the daily average of col1.
I started with this:

```
df.groupby('date')['col1'].mean()
```

That didn't work because of the hours, minutes and seconds.
Later, I tried this:

```
df["day"] = df["date"].dt.day
df.groupby("day")["col1"].mean().plot(kind="line")
```

I almost did it, but the column day is not actually the day, but a number which represents the position of the day in the year, I guess. So any ideas on how to make this plot?

Comment: Hope this will solve your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3276190/14407099

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC:

groupby date instead of day:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)["col1"].mean().plot(kind="line",rot=25)
#you don't need to create a column date for this directly pass date in groupby()
```

OR

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.normalize())["col1"].mean().plot(kind="line",rot=25)
```

Optional(you can also do this by these 2 but the above 2 fits best for your data and condition since the below ones will create unnecessary dates and NaN's):

```
#via pd.Grouper():
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='1D'))["col1"].mean().dropna().plot(kind="line")
#OR
#via dt.floor():
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('1D'))["col1"].mean().dropna().plot(kind="line")
```

output(for given sample data):

[image]

Comment: Two wonderful answers, thank you so much!!!! Regarding the GROUPER answer, I'm getting this error: "TypeError: 'TimeGrouper' object is not subscriptable". Any idea about what's happening?

Comment: @dummmmf ohh sorry I forgot to add `)` so updated answer....kindly have a look...btw use 1st method as it will be faster in your case ***:)***

Answer (score 1):

Since this question has `seaborn` and `plotly` tags as well,

[`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) performs this operation **without** the need for [`groupby mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) as the default estimator will compute the mean value per `x` instance. To remove error shading set `ci=None`.

Imports and setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2020-01-01 00:01:020', '2020-01-02 00:01:020',
             '2020-01-02 00:01:000', '2020-01-02 00:01:021',
             '2020-02-05 20:11:010', '2020-02-05 10:01:020'],
    'col1': [20, 10, 20, 20, 30, 10],
    'col2': [500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Plotting Code:

```
# Seaborn Line Plot x is the date, y is col1 default estimator is mean
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df['date'].dt.date, y='col1', ci=None)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=45)  # Make X ticks easier to read
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot 1 seaborn]

---

For plotly take the [`groupby mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and create a [`px.line`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line).

Imports and setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2020-01-01 00:01:020', '2020-01-02 00:01:020',
             '2020-01-02 00:01:000', '2020-01-02 00:01:021',
             '2020-02-05 20:11:010', '2020-02-05 10:01:020'],
    'col1': [20, 10, 20, 20, 30, 10],
    'col2': [500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Plotting code:

```
plot_values = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)["col1"].mean()
fig = px.line(plot_values)
fig.show()
```

[image: plot 2]

Answer (score 0):

What do you want exactly? the date without time?
try this:

```
df["day"] = df["date"].apply(lambda l: l.date())
```